# Unexpected '<' when i hit any GET request Postman

Tags: postman

[.p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUZ6e.png)

Any one please let me know what would be the solution to resolve this probelm

Answer (score 1):

That is because you're trying to parse HTML.

When you hit google.com the response is actually 'HTML' (The webpage)
And when you do JSON.parse on HTML it'll give you an unexpected '<' error.

Try using this url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

And then check if it still fails for you or not.